# Google Chrome instantly starts with my-search.com

Tags: google-chrome

mainly when i start my google chrome, I receive "http://www.my-search.com/?aid=5156&zoneid=9560-1018" this page as the home page. I am fed up of this and tried solutions from various sources, but cant find the solution. So please help me to sort it out.
Thanks in  advance.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2765944?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

If this doesn't work

1. Go to your desktop and right click on chrome shortcut icon.
2. Go to propertied->Shortcut and check whether the Start in: has entry like this  "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application". If your installation directory is different then it might be a little different.But make sure that Start in: has Google\Chrome\Application and nothing else.
3. Also check the Target path: it should be something like this "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" the directory might be different but the rest should be similar.

If none of the above works try uninstalling your chrome and use Chrome clean up tool and reinstall your chrome.